# Laravel seed after migrating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, migration, laravel-5

Is there something I can put in my migrations to automatically seed the table with test data once the migration has completed?

Or do you *have* to seed separately?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can call `migrate:refresh` with the `--seed` option to automatically seed after the migrations are complete:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

This will rollback and re-run all your migrations and run all seeders afterwards.

---

Just as a little extra, you can also always use `Artisan::call()` to run an artisan command from inside the application:

```
Artisan::call('db:seed');
```

or

```
Artisan::call('db:seed', array('--class' => 'YourSeederClass'));
```

if you want specific seeder class.

Comment: I did as you told and It was all right until it comes to production. Production freezes with this. Please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50458656/database-gets-stuck-in-migration-with-seeder-on-production-with-force-in-larav) for details.

Comment: Be aware, if you run this in production after you have data other than seed data in DB, you will loose that data.

Answer (score 63):

### If you don't want to delete existing data and want to seed after migrating

[lukasgeiter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463666/164998) is correct for test data, but running following artisan command

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

in production will refresh your database removing any data entered or updated from frontend.

If you want to seed your database along a migration (example rolling out an update to your application keeping existing data), like adding a new table countries  along with seed data, you can do the following:

Create a database seeder example YourSeeder.php in database/seeds and your location table migration

```
class YourTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tablename', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name',1000);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });

        $seeder = new YourTableSeeder();
        $seeder->run();
    }

    /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tablename');
    }
}
```

Run `composer dump-autoload` if there is a php class not found error for  YourTableSeeder class.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo. From within a migration this is really readable. Furthermore, if you call a command from within the migration, you would also need to add the --force flag to prevent the system for asking for confirmation in production-servers.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, new table with default content without changing the hole database.

Answer (score 6):

While [lukasgeiter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463666/164998) is correct, I'd like to elaborate on your second question.

> Or do you have to seed separately?

Yes. Since you're talking about *test data* you should avoid coupling *seeding*  with *migration*. Of course if this were not test data, but application data, you could always make inserting data part of the migration.

As an aside, if you want to seed your data as part of [testing](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/testing#helper-methods), you can call `$this->seed()` from within your Laravel test case.

Answer (score 2):

Tips for running migration and seeder-specific file for Laravel Framework

Migrate

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/fileName.php
```

Rollback

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --path=/database/migrations/fileName.php
```

Refresh

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/fileName.php
```

Seeder

```
php artisan db:seed --class=classNameTableSeeder
```

Thanks