# Database gets stuck in migration with seeder on production with --force in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations, laravel-seeding

Database gets stuck in migration with seeder on production with --force in Laravel. Same effect I have on Laravel Homestead and EC2 AWS running Amazone linux. No messages in laravel.log.

It just never ends. If I halt it with `<ctrl>+<c>`, I see the table created but seeder was not run, the table is empty.

Detalis:

My migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 50);
        $table->decimal('price', 8, 2); //up to 999,999.99
    });

    Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'ProductsSeeder']);
}
```

I call it like so:

```
$ php artisan migrate --force
```

my .env

```
#APP_ENV=local

APP_DEBUG=false
```

the database seeds.

```
class ProductsSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('products')->insert([
            'id'                   => 1,
            'name'                 => 'super product',
            'price'                => 999.99,
        ]);
    }
```

*Tested Laravel 5.6*

Comment: Can you post the seeder code?

Comment: Posted the seeder code, but it is sad that the comment requesting the seeder has attracted 2 vote-ups, when it has nothing to do with the seeder code.

Comment: What happens when you do the `php artisan db:seed` command from terminal? Does it work as expected? You could also try running migrate with the verbose flag `php artisan migrate --force -vvv` to see if you get any error messages.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev very hard for everyone else to tell that without having the access to it

Comment: This class is not a part of default seed, but if I do `php artisan db:seed --class=[ProductsSeeder]` - then everything goes fine.

Comment: @devk, good point. Agreed and voted up.

Comment: No output when using the `-vvv` verbose flag? I wonder if you also need to add the `--force` flag to the seed call in this case, as you are using it on the migration?

Comment: @Jeemusu, Bingo!!! You saved me. Thank you.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev Added an answer.

Comment: Using `--force` and/or `-vvv` does not seem to make a difference. My config is correct.

Comment: check out my comment to the accepted answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try including the `-vvv` flag in your migration command, this will increase the verbosity of any messages, which might uncover the problem.

> --verbose (-v|vv|vvv) Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

`$ php artisan migrate --force`

As for the problem itself, try including the `--force` flag in your `db:seed` call, as you have included it in the migration.

`Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'ProductsSeeder', '--force' => true,]);`

Comment: `'--force' => true,` did help. Thank you.

Comment: `'--force' => true` does not work without call migration with --force.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue running `php artisan migrate` and nothing happens, stays stuck.
`--force` or verbose wouldn't help.

The problem I had is the `DB_PORT` in .env was not set correctly.

Comment: I have the same problem, it's getting stuck even when usimg --force. I checked the port and it's pointing to the right port (3306). Any other idea?

Comment: @MrCujo I have the same issue